# How to load and apply a 3rd-party stylesheet into a NextJS component after CSS-in-JS globals?

Tags: next.js, styling, css-in-js, stitches

I've got a problem with the loading order in a NextJS app.

We use [Stitches](https://stitches.dev/) CSS-in-JS, which provides [`globalCss()`](https://stitches.dev/docs/api#globalcss) for loading global styles like resetters/normalizers and it gets invoked in `_app.tsx`.

On the other hand, a component that requires an external stylesheet uses:

```
import "@third-party/styles.css"
```

But unfortunately it gets triggered **too early**, i.e. **before** the `globalCss()` invocation. As a result, global reset-styles override the component styles.

So how to load a 3rd-pary stylesheet **after** `globalCss()` styles?